# How to check if checkbox is checked in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML form with fields: `input`, `textarea`.
All fields have attribute `required` and submit button have:

```
<div ng-click="Share()" ng-disabled="shareForm.$invalid"</div>
```

How I can check if checkbox is checked or not and disable button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "ng-model" in angular

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"/>
<button ng-disabled="!checked"> MyInput </button>
```

Comment: But outside of button? I can?

Comment: Of course : the `ng-model` named "checked" will be available everywhere (you must be inside your controller call `ng-controller` of course)

Answer (score 3):

Put `ng-model` binding on your input:

```
<div ng-click="Share()" ng-model="checked" ng-disabled="shareForm.$invalid"</div>
```

And inside your "Share" function:

```
if($scope.checked){
   //do some action if checkbox is checked
}
```